# Hindsight experience replay: strategy for sampling goals

Tags: reinforcement-learning

The authors of [Hindsight Experience Replay](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.01495.pdf) list out several strategies for sampling a set of additional goals $G$ in Section 4.5:

- **final** - corresponds with final state of environment,
- **future** — replay with k random states which come from the same episode as the transition being replayed and were observed after it,
- **episode** — replay with k random states coming from the same episode as the transition
  being replayed,
- **random** — replay with k random states encountered so far in the whole training procedure.

My interpretation of the **future** method is then that we can only select k random states if the current transition being replayed has already happened in the episode, so this is at minimum the second time we've seen the current transition. This seems *very unlikely* if working in an environment with a large state space (especially with continuous features). Am I missing something obvious in the interpretation of how to implement this strategy?

Answer (score 1):

I’ve been there for quite a while until i read the implementation of thr algorithm in OpenAI Baselines library, you can find it on Github.
Basically as of what i understood from the algorithm the K factor mainly adjusts the percentage of sampled data (being replayed for the update step in Q weights) that if we sample 1 transition without HER we sample another K with HER. This can be implemenated in the prescribed fashion if we sampled a batch of data and replayed K/1+k with HER by simply changing their goals by other states observed at any time in the future

Comment: I think what Karim meant was this method! [Her sampler](https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/master/baselines/her/her_sampler.py#L4)